# Drupal 7 - How to display the TID of a term reference field in a content type?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have a content type called video and a term reference field called category. I want to be able to output the TID of the term reference field in my content display. Is there a way to do this to expose the TID of the term? I'm able to generate a link from the term in the manage displayed settings, but it has an alias to it so it won't show the tid in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to make a new field formatter.  You need to implement two hooks, [`hook_field_formatter_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7) and [`hook_field_formatter_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7).  The info hook tells Drupal about your formatter and the view does the heavy lifting.  You can then use this on the **Manage Display** for the field in your content type.

The easiest way to do this is to clone them from [taxnomy.module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/7), and modify.  Something like this would be a start

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_formatter_info() {
  return array(
    'MYMODULE_term_name_with_tid' => array(
      'label' => t('Term name + tid'),
      'field types' => array('taxonomy_term_reference'),
    ),
  );
}

function MYMODULE_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();

  switch ($display['type']) {
    case 'MYMODULE_term_name_with_tid':
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        $name = ($item['tid'] != 'autocreate' ? $item['taxonomy_term']->name  : $item['name']);
        $element[$delta] = array(
          '#markup' => check_plain($name) . '(' . $item['tid'] . ')',
        );
      }
      break;
  }

  return $element;
}
```

Comment: thanks! working great. i just needed the tid, so i removed the line that starts with $name

Comment: @duckx Glad I could help.  I literally just wrote a similar formatter the day before.  If you just need the tid, then you can simlify further to `'#markup' => $item['tid']`,